# See communication in WiFi with known password

Tags: wifi, decryption, wpa2-psk

I know the password to a certain router which uses `WPA2-PSK-CCMP + WPS + ESS`, is it possible to watch the communication between devices and the router unencrypted assuming I know the password to the router?

I tried to sniff traffic in monitor mode and for some reason I didn't see a key transferred (which means I cannot crack the communication). Is there something I'm missing?

If you can break it, how is it possible? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

You need the handshake packages captured. You can force a client to re-authenticate again with a lot of tools so you will instantly get this.

Then you just need a tool that can decrypt WPA and give the key to this tool.

Wireshark is an example for such a tool:
[image: Image from their wiki]